# Javascript - make every other character of string in other color

Tags: javascript, css, string

I try to make every other character of string to get other color.

Javascript

```
    var s='JavaScript string one.';
    var c='This is second string.';

    var sc = s.concat(c);

    var sclenght = sc.lenght;

    var screz = "";
    var redcolor = true;
    for(i=0;i<sclenght;i++){
        var schar = sc.charAt(i);
        if(schar == " "){
            screz += schar; 
        } else if(redcolor){
            screz += "<span>" + schar + "</span>";
            redcolor = !redcolor;   
        } else{
            screz += schar;
            redcolor = !redcolor;
        }
    }
    document.write(screz);
```

CSS

```
    span{color: red;}
```

I didn't get any output, and I don't know what is the problem in code, If anyone can help me, thanks.

Comment: With typos corrected (`lenght` should be `length`), your posted code works perfectly well: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5yx16pkg/).

Answer (score 1):

length is wrongly spelled. You used lenght insted of length

sc.length;

Comment: I make var sclenght before for loop.
var sclenght = sc.lenght;

EDIT. I am sorry, I didn't see that is error in typing, thank you man.

Comment: there is a mistake in length spelling. You can see  ther error info in browser console.

Comment: you used sc.lenght insted of sc.length

Comment: @KishoreIndraganti This would not error, it would fail silently. `sc.lenght` would just spit out `undefined`, and `0 < undefined === false` so the loop would simple not run.

Comment: Happy to help you. Try to use browser console as much as you can.

Comment: @Oka I agree with you .